# Add callback to .addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this straightforward event listener registration pattern:

```
 function registerElement(){
     var element = document.getElementById("element");
     element.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);
 }

 function sayHello(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("Hello from " + this.id);
 }

 registerElement();
```

Now, I'd like to add a callback function, say registerElement(callback). The idea is to execute some function after "element" gets a click, and the pseudocode might look something like this:

```
 function registerElement(callback){
     var element = document.getElementById("element");
     element.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false); //<--not sure what to do here to add callback to sayHello
 }

 function sayHello(event, callback){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log("Hello from " + this.id);
     callback;
 }

 function cleanup(){
     console.log("Hello from cleanup");
 }

 registerElement(cleanup);
```

I'm trying to avoid using an anonymous function in registerElement to make sayHello() more reusable. I looked at bind, but that seems to focus on controlling which "this" gets sent over to the event listener function. Any other ideas?

Thanks for tips!

Comment: `element.addEventListener("click", sayHello.bind(null, callback), false);`  but then it's be `function sayHello(callback, event){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listeners are executed in the order added to an element. Again, provided `sayHello` does nothing asynchronous that would require the `cleanup` callback to be be delayed and called asynchronously as well, you could just add another event listener:

```
function registerElement(callback){
     var element = document.getElementById("element");
     element.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);
     element.addEventListener("click", callback, false); 
}
```

If cleanup is dependent on `sayHello` completing an aysnchronous task, the design probably needs reviewing to use promises or async/await functions.

A more generic registration function could parameterize the element id, the type of event and take an arbitrary number of callbacks, (including `sayHello`) as in this example:

```js
function register( elementId, eventType, ...callbacks) {
    const element = document.getElementById( elementId);
    for( const callback of callbacks) {
        element.addEventListener( eventType, callback, false);
    }
}

// test
const sayHello = e=>console.log("hello");
const cleanup =  e=>console.log("cleanup");
register( "myButton", "click", sayHello, cleanup);
```

```html
<button type"button" id="myButton">myButton</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example -- and the register function is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a mix of responsibilities, a recommendation is to execute the callback function outside of the function `sayHello`, otherwise the function `sayHello` will be tied to a second param `callback`:

*This approach is assuming that `sayHello` doesn't execute any async logic within it*

```
function registerElement(callback){
   var element = document.getElementById("element");
   element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
      sayHello(e);
      callback();
   }, false);
}
```