# Javascript - use callback with addEventListener for "remove all" button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm adding a "remove all" button to my chrome extension which as the name suggests should serve to remove all saved links.

The button works only after I have performed some other action first (adding a link, removing a link etc) but of course, I want it to work right away.

I have read that this may be due to the code being asynchronous so I tried introducing a callback function with the help of this question: [Add callback to .addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102438/add-callback-to-addeventlistener) however, it's still performing the same way it did before so maybe that wasn't the issue after all, or I may have read the other question wrong. I appreciate any tips so thank you in advance. I will try to figure it out myself in the meantime.

```js
var urlList = [];
var i = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getUrlListAndRestoreInDom();
  // event listener for the button inside popup window
  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', addLink);
});

function addLink() {
  var url = document.getElementById("saveLink").value;
  addUrlToListAndSave(url);
  addUrlToDom(url);
}

function getUrlListAndRestoreInDom() {
  chrome.storage.local.get({
    urlList: []
  }, function(data) {
    urlList = data.urlList;
    urlList.forEach(function(url) {
      addUrlToDom(url);
    });
  });
}

function addUrlToDom(url) {
  // change the text message
  document.getElementById("saved-pages").innerHTML = "<h2>Saved pages</h2>";
  var newEntry = document.createElement('li');
  var newLink = document.createElement('a');
  var removeButton = document.createElement('button');

  removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
  removeButton.type = "button";
  removeButton.className = "remove";
  removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var anchor = this.previousElementSibling;
    var url = anchor.getAttribute("href");
    removeUrlAndSave(url);
    this.parentNode.remove();
  });

  newLink.textContent = url;
  newLink.setAttribute('href', url);
  newLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  newEntry.appendChild(newLink);
  newEntry.appendChild(removeButton);

  newEntry.className = "listItem";

  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newEntry);
}

function removeUrlAndSave(url) {
  var index = urlList.indexOf(url);
  if (index != -1) {
    urlList.splice(index, 1);
    saveUrlList();
  }
}


function addUrlToListAndSave(url) {
  urlList.push(url);
  saveUrlList();
  //}
}

function saveUrlList(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({
    urlList
    // }, function() {
    //   if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    //     //If there was no callback provided, don't try to call it.
    //     callback();
    //   }
    // });
  });

  function removeMe(i) {
    var fullList = documents.getElementsByClassName('listItem');
    listItem[i].parentNode.removeChild(listItem[i]);
  }

  function removeAll() {
    var removeList = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");
    while (removeList[0]) {
      removeList[0].parentNode.removeChild(removeList[0]);
    };
  }

  function registerElement(callback) {
    var element = document.getElementById("remove-all-button");
    element.addEventListener("click", callback);
  }

  registerElement(removeAll);
```

```css
 #list {
 min-height: 360px;
 max-height: 360px;
 width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <span id="hot-button"><a href="hot-drops.html">Hot Drops</a></span>

    <li id="removeAll">
      <button id="remove-all-button"> Remove All</button>
    </li>

    <span id="saved-pages"></span>
    <div>
      <ul id="list"></ul>

    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="button" id="save" value="Add">
  <input type="text" id="saveLink" name="member" value=""><br/>
  <span id="settings-button"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/drkobnLu/

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem might be without an example of the HTML you have also.

Comment: That's so strange! I've been scratching my head all day trying to get this to work. I'll update with the rest of the code maybe the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to how things work around here. I updated the code in the text box above. Might be worth mentioning the the list items I want to remove are added using Javascript in response to the user's actions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1w69bo8k/ I think this link should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drkobnLu/4/)

```
had to write this line to post link
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1w69bo8k/ - you made a lot of mistakes, where you put certain code, to using variables I never saw them defined anywhere in code
(you keep editing the question, I went from this fiddle you provided)

change back to your getUrlListAndRestoreInDom function, deleted the storage code

you update the storage and the urlList manually, rather do it after the update of local is successful

Comment: Post the code here in a stack snippet instead of just at jsfiddle.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: This code runs perfectly. Thank you WASD and Barmar for the edits. Just trying to wrap my head around all the changes you made at the moment.

Comment: I see the "removeMe" function and rest of the code for removing individual buttons has been removed but I'm unsure what part of the code performs this function instead. I'm guessing it wasn't necessary to begin with. Could you explain please?

Comment: Oh my bad! I see it. For some reason, I thought you had to call the code explicitly after the fact or something when you wanted to remove a list, and reference it specifically in a loop. Thanks a lot for your help. :)